# Scanning elements one by one and comparing them

Tags: java

I have to do some homework for my programming class. The task is to take a text-document as input for a short program and to remove all the numbers that are duplicates and print those single numbers out. This works just fine when there are two numbers following each other, but as soon as there are three or more, my program sees those as "new" numbers, thus printing out a wrong answer.

I have already tried two scanners that read the same file, but it seems like you can't scan a file twice with different scanners.
I would usually do this task with java.util.ArrayList, but we are not allowed to use it, since we didn't have it in our lecture yet.
I could expand it to be able to compare three numbers following each other, but it would make the program too complicated. It seems like there has to be an easier way.

```
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean hasPrinted = false;

    while(scanner1.hasNext()){

        int x = scanner1.nextInt();
        if(scanner1.hasNext()){
            int y = scanner1.nextInt();
            if(x != y){
                System.out.println(x);
                System.out.println(y);
                hasPrinted = true;
            }
        }
        if(!hasPrinted) System.out.println(x);
        hasPrinted = false; 
    }
```

The input is: java RemoveDuplicates < input.txt

When the text document is something like `1 8 3 3 5 4 4 4 9`,the output is expected to be `1 8 3 5 4 9`. The output I get is `1 8 3 5 4 4 9`.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: First read the file and and place its contents in an array then check for duplicates in array. if you do like this the problem becomes simpler

Comment: Are you allowed to use maps? what things are allowed? what about number arrays? as in `int[]`

Comment: tried this already, but the text document can be varying in size, meaning I will have to go through it once to count the number of elements in the text-document to initialize an array that size and go through it once more to fill the array with the elements. But I can't seem to figure out how to scan the document twice.

Comment: I am basically only allowed to use the class Scanner and Arrays.

Comment: A very simple way to achieve your goal is to use some implantation of `Set` - since a property of `Set` is that all elements must be unique, it would be a great data structure to store the numbers in.

Answer (score 0):

Let's handle the 1 8 3 3 5 4 4 4 8 case too.
Basically we have an array of integers we've seen. And if during the runtime we realize the array is not big enough, we replace it with a bigfer one.

```java
final static int BLOCK = 1024;

// How we expamd our array. I use arraycopy which is much faster than a loop
// if you're not allowed to use it, resort to a simple loop.
static Integer expand(Integer[] source) {
   Integer[] expanded = new Integer[source.length + BLOCK];
   System.arraycopy(source, 0, expanded, 0, source.length);
   return expanded;
}

// ....

Integer[] alreadySeen = new Integer[BLOCK]; // not int[], to allow nulls.
bailout:
while(scanner1.hasNext()){
        int x = scanner1.nextInt();
        int i; // we need this out of loop context too.

        for(i = 0; i< alreadySeen.length; i++)
            if(alreadySeen[i] == null)
                 break; // nothing furthur too look for.
            else if(Objects.equals(alreadySeen[i], (Integer) x))
                  continue bailout; // yes, we have seen it, bail out.

        // If we have reached here, we didn't hit "continue" up there and it's a new number

        if(i == alreadySeen.length) // overflow, allocate more
             alreadySeen = expand(alreadySeen);
        alreadySeen[i] = x;
        System.out.println(x);
  }
```

What we have implemented here, is kind of an inefficient ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> alreadyPrinted = new ArrayList<>();
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    int number = scanner.nextInt();
    if (!alreadyPrinted.contains(number)){
         System.out.print(number);
         alreadyPrinted.add(number);
    }
}
```